# Hatcher's algebraic topology problem 1.1.10

Tags: algebraic-topology

> From the isomorphism $\pi_1(X \times Y, (x_0 , y_0 )) \approx \pi_1(X, x_0 )\times \pi_1 (Y , y_0)$ it follows that loops in $X \times \{y_0 \}$ and $\{x_0 \} \times Y$ represent commuting elements of $\pi_1(X\times Y, (x_0 , y_0 ))$. Construct an explicit homotopy demonstrating this.

I tried to get some intuition from letting $X=\Bbb R, Y =\Bbb R$ so I would be looking at the space $\Bbb R^2$ which is path-connected so $\pi_1(X \times Y, (x_0 , y_0 )) \approx \pi_1(X, x_0 )\times \pi_1 (Y , y_0)$.

If I know pick a loop of $X \times \{y_0\}$ and a loop of $\{x_0 \} \times Y$ I get something like the following

[image]

where the loops should actually be "on top" of the blue and pink lines. What I don't quite understand now is that what is meant by commuting elements of $\pi_1(\Bbb R^2, (x_0,y_0))$? Is it so that I can get to $y_0$ by starting with a loop from $x_0$ and then from the intersection I "traverse" to $y_0$?

Comment: $\pi_1$ is a group under path composition. (On the other hand, $\pi_1(\mathbb{R^2})$ is trivial, so nothing interesting happens there.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: imagine someone using one of those heavy exercise-ropes. (Or, if you prefer, imagine a soliton – if this is too vague I will fill in the details of the image)

Your two subgroups are $\pi_1(X,x_0)\times \{e\}$ and $\{e\} \times \pi_1(Y,y_0)$. An element $\phi_X$ in the first of these subgroups can be taken to be stationary in the $Y$-component, and an element $\psi_Y$ in the second can be taken to be stationary in the $X$-component. Then $\phi_X \cdot \psi_Y$ is a loop starting at $(x_0,y_0)$, running through a fixed copy of $X$ (namely $X\times \{y_0\}$), returning to $(x_0,y_0)$, then running through $\{x_0\}\times Y$. Is it possible to build a homotopy that makes this loop first conduct some of its $Y$-component business, then conduct its $X$-component business in a different slice $X\times \{y’\}$ (or, more suggestively, $X\times \{y_t\}$), before finally finishing up its $Y$-route?

Comment: I don't think this loop $\phi_X \cdot \psi_Y$ can "conduct any of it's business first in $\{x_0\} \times Y$ and then in $X \times \{y_0\}$ before finishing up in $\{x_0\} \times Y$" as it would seem to break continuity?

Comment: Perhaps the phrasing wasn’t clear – that should be how this loop behaves while you’re deforming it to $\psi_Y\cdot \phi_X$. Note that I do not suggest the $X$ component activity should take place along $X\times \{y_0\}$ – that would indeed be discontinuous – but along $X\times \{y’\}$, where $(x_0,y’)$ is whatever point you left off at when initially following part of $\psi_Y$ through $\{x_0\}\times Y$.